# Fetch event handler without event.respondWith()

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it valid to return from a `fetch` event handler in a service worker without specifying what to `respondWith`?  What happens in that case?  Is the fetch event still handled correctly in the default manner?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    if ( /* don't fancy handling this one */ ) {
        // what happens in this case?
        return;
    }
    event.respondWith(
        // do some stuff and return a promise for a response
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't call `event.respondWith`, the browser handles the fetch as it usually would.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that was probably the case but I couldn't find anything definitive out there.

Answer (score 0):

Now on ios safari request will hang up without `event.respondWith()`